# Instance name undefined JS error - Adobe Animate CC

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, adobe, animate-cc

I am trying to create an replay button in my Adobe Animate CC HTML5 project.  I've set the instance name in the property panel to "ReplayBtn". In a frame on my JS layer, I'm trying this :

```
this.ReplayBtn.addEventListener("click", (function () { this.gotoAndPlay(0); }).bind(this));
```

But I get an error of *"Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"*. By inspecting "this", I can see that the instance name is not what I specified but "instance_3" instead.  Updating the code to this works fine :

```
this.instance_3.addEventListener("click", (function () { this.gotoAndPlay(0); }).bind(this));
```

Why can't I use the instance name I've specified in the property panel ?

Answer (score 0):

Comment #7 on this forum thread pointed me to a solution :

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2349302

I removed the button from the timeline and re-added it. Bibbity boppity, it works as expected. A bug I guess ?

EDIT: Lesson of the day, add the instance name before you screw around with the instance on the timeline.